# Silex: translation not working in Twig

Tags: php, twig, silex

Currently, I develop a website by using the PHP micro-framework **Silex**. Now I try to use "*TranslationServiceProvider*" to translate my website into different languages. To achieve this, I have set the "*locale*" parameter :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'locale' => 'pt'
));
```

Then, in my controller, I call the function "setLocale", like this:

```
$app['translator']->setLocale('it');
```

Now, if I display, always in my controller, the result of the translation its works fine:

```
$app['translator']->trans("hello"); // return "Buongiorno" 
$app['translator']->getLocale(); // return "it"
```

But, if I call the same function in my template Twig, translation does not work:

```
{{ app.translator.trans('hello') }} // return: "Olá"
{{ app.request.locale }} // return: "pt"
```

So, I don't understand: translation works fine in my controller but when I want access translations in Twig, nothing happens.

Do you have any idea about what's going on?

Comment: Silly question but... Is this template being rendered by the same controller that changes the locale?

Comment: Yes, I change locale in the same controller that render template.

Comment: show full code for controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution to resolve my problem. In my "app.php" file, I have added the following code :

```
$app->before(function () use ($app) {
    if ($locale = $app['request']->get('lang') or $locale  = $app['request']->getSession()->get('_locale')) {
        $app['locale'] = $locale;
        $app['request']->setLocale($locale);
    }
});
```

Then, I've written a function in my controller to change language:

```
public function changeLanguageAction(Request $request, Application $app, $language)
{
    $app['request']->getSession()->set('_locale', $language);

    return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate('index'));
}
```

Now, when I call "changeLanguage" function, all the translations work fine.

I don't know if this solution is a good practice but it works...